# Does a symbol like this or a similar thing already exsist and has its meaning or not?

Tags: symbols

I have this symbol sketch:

[image]

Does it have an existing meaning?

Comment: It's also John Paul Jones' logo within Led Zeppelin! https://www.google.ca/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjdrbTf-4PRAhXo5YMKHcGpDbcQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F559431584935440163%2F&psig=AFQjCNFUzAo3fIiz1wbVQ64b5z-T2yD5xg&ust=1482364368752604

Comment: Kinda reminds me of radioactivity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called a [Trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) and it's a rather common symbol in both arts and iconography. If the outer 'leaves' are pointed, it's known as a [Triquetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra).

Both symbols have seen a lot of use, as especially the Triquetra Wikipedia article confirms. Among others, it was a Celtic symbol adapted by Christianity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50437/discussion-on-answer-by-vincent-does-a-symbol-like-this-or-a-similar-thing-alrea).

Answer (score 5):

This looks (to my eyes at least) rather like a very basic **Celtic Knot** aka a **Triquesta** or **Trinity Knot**. There are lots of references to these things to be found on the internet if you search for the above words and phrases.

This is a very old symbol so the original meaning can be a bit lost and different people attribute different meanings to them. A commonly accepted meaning is that the three points / loops indicate mind, body and soul. Also, the fact that Celtic Knots have do ends is often taken to represent the never-ending cycle of life.

Comment: I was just about to add... It also looks like a Trefoil Knot, but this has been covered in Vincent's answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Trefoil" is a name for a sort of universal three-lobed shape that is based on a type of plant, like a clover. Google's definition and images are here:

https://www.google.com/search?q=trefoil&rlz=1C1VFKB_enUS601US601&oq=trefoil&aqs=chrome..69i57.1575j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Because it is such a basic, simple shape, you see it expressed in everything from architectural decoration (think gothic church windows) to the symbol for radiation danger.

Comment: And biohazards.